# Can I leave programs running in ubuntu while switching back to Chromebook?

Tags: 14.04

I want to keep programs running in the background on Ubuntu 14.04 while I switch back to Chromebook. Is it possible to use this feature? I have Samsung 3 Chromebook. I would greatly appreciate your help thanks!

Comment: Are you dualbooting? If yes, then no, that is not how dual booting works.

Comment: How can I dualboot?

Comment: I was asking about your setup. As I understood your question, you are already dual-booting. This means your chromebook has Ubuntu and Chrome OS installed in parallel. However, since only one operating system is active at any time, you cannot run Ubuntu applicat in the background while being in ChromeOS. If your setup is something different, you should modify your question to sescribe it.

Comment: Correct, I have both Ubuntu and Chrome OS installed on my laptop. In that case, why is Ubuntu running slow? For example when I play YouTube videos or open tabs there is a delay and takes much longer when compared to my Chrome OS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Chromebooks is a very lightweight PC. To do what you want would require [virtualization](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/L/linux_virtualization.html), and although the N3060 Celeron CPU is [technically capable of virtualization](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/91832/intel-celeron-processor-n3060-2m-cache-up-to-2-48-ghz.html), you wouldn't like it when it gets pokey.